# ReactJS: Passing the object rendered by a component as an attribute to another component?

Tags: reactjs

I'm using React 16.2.0, having trouble doing something it seems *should* be doable, but I'm new to React, so needing a sanity check here.

The app is a log viewer which fetches log entries from a backend database. I'm wanting to have a Paging component which maintains a log data pool, fetches more logs when the pool gets low, and on request grabs the next chunk to be displayed (dataChunk below).

I'm returning dataChunk in the render() method of the Paging component. I also have a simple View component that just renders a chunk of log entries contained in dataChunk.

As seen below, I'm wanting to have the dataChunk rendered/returned from Paging component passed as an attribute to the View component:

```
render() {
    return(
        <View dataChunk={<Paging chunkCb={this.chunkCb} state={pagingState}}/>
    );
 }
```

What is actually showing up in this.props.dataChunk in View is a react.element object (basically the Paging object). Paging is never instantiated/mounted.

Is what I'm wanting possible in React? Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to close the Paging tag properly:

```
render() {
    return(
        <View dataChunk={<Paging chunkCb={this.chunkCb} state={pagingState} />}/>
    );
 }
```

However, instead of passing a Component as a prop, just compose `Paging` inside the `render()` function of `View` component definition, unless `View` is a third-party library that uses [Render Props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) pattern.

Comment: Thanks Eric. I didn't elaborate on the workings of my application, but I ended up going a different direction altogether anyway. I was needing to add paging logic to multiple components, reusing the paging logic implemented in the Paging component. I ended up implementing using a wrapped component.